# Drop down Menu, in Next-Auth's CredentialsProvider()

Tags: next.js, credentials, next-auth

I'm implementing the "CredentialsProvider" from Next-Auth, so far I've see examples where I can only add text fields in it like 'usernames' and 'passwords'.

Is it possible to add a 'Menu list' kind of thing? Which will basically give us some options to select from? I'm basically doing this to provide an option to the user to either login as a User or Admin, by selecting any one of them from the drop down menu (something similar to the design in the image below)

[image]

I have tried the 'radio' option but that's not what I'm looking for.

Answer (score 0):

The Credentials Provider in NextAuth.js is primarily designed for simple username/password authentication. It doesn't provide built-in support for more complex forms or dropdown menus as you've described. However, you can achieve your desired functionality by customizing the sign-in page.

Here's how you can do it:

**Create a Custom Sign-in Page:** Instead of using the default sign-in page provided by NextAuth.js, you can create a custom sign-in page in your Next.js application. This custom page can include any form elements you need, including dropdown menus.

**Implement Dropdown Menu:** In your custom sign-in page, you can add an HTML  element to create a dropdown menu. You can populate this dropdown with options like "User" and "Admin."

```
<select name="role">
  <option value="user">User</option>
  <option value="admin">Admin</option>
</select>
```

**Handle Form Submission:** When the user submits the form, you can access the selected value from the dropdown menu in your form submission handler. Depending on the selected role ("User" or "Admin"), you can then use the appropriate logic to authenticate the user.
Here's a simplified example of a custom sign-in page with a dropdown menu:

```
import { useState } from 'react';
import { signIn } from 'next-auth/react';

export default function CustomSignIn() {
  const [role, setRole] = useState('user'); // Default role is "User"

  const handleSignIn = async (e) => {
    e.preventDefault();

    // Use the selected role when signing in
    const result = await signIn('credentials', {
      role,
      // Other credentials like username and password
    });

    // Handle the sign-in result as needed
  };

  return (
    <div>
      <h2>Custom Sign In</h2>
      <form onSubmit={handleSignIn}>
        <label>
          Role:
          <select name="role" value={role} onChange={(e) => setRole(e.target.value)}>
            <option value="user">User</option>
            <option value="admin">Admin</option>
          </select>
        </label>
        {/* Other input fields like username and password */}
        <button type="submit">Sign In</button>
      </form>
    </div>
  );
}
```

With this approach, you have full control over the sign-in form's appearance and behavior, including adding dropdown menus for user roles.

Remember that the Credentials Provider's primary purpose is to handle authentication based on the provided credentials (e.g., username and password). It doesn't dictate the structure or appearance of your sign-in page, giving you the flexibility to implement custom forms as needed.

**Note:**

By default, NextAuth.js automatically creates simple, unbranded authentication pages for handling Sign in, Sign out, Email Verification and displaying error messages.

To add a custom login page, you can use the pages option:
Make sure to add the pages property with the key signIn in the NextAuth Configuration, It tells NextAuth that what **custom page** to use:

```
  pages: {
    signIn: "/login",
    // signOut: "/login",
    // error: "/auth/error", // Error code passed in query string as ?error=
    // verifyRequest: "/auth/verify-request", // (used for check email message)
    // newUser: "/auth/new-user", // New users will be directed here on first sign in (leave the property out if not of interest)
  },
```